# pyclustertend in Google Colab (python)

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Has anybody tried to use the library pyclustertend? It is not present right now in Google Colab.

A friend explained to me that it is possible to install libraries that are not already in Google Colab just by typing at the beginning of my code:

```
!pip install "name of the library"
```

So by typing:

```
!pip install pyclustertend
```

It starts installing but at the end I get the error:

> ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts. tensorflow 2.12.0 requires numpy<1.24,>=1.22, but you have numpy 1.20.3 which is incompatible. jaxlib 0.4.7+cuda11.cudnn86 requires numpy>=1.21, but you have numpy 1.20.3 which is incompatible. jax 0.4.8 requires numpy>=1.21, but you have numpy 1.20.3 which is incompatible. cmdstanpy 1.1.0 requires numpy>=1.21, but you have numpy 1.20.3 which is incompatible.

However, right after it says Successfully installed llvmlite-0.37.0 numba-0.54.1 numpy-1.20.3 pyclustertend-1.8.2.

So I crossed my fingers and hoped it went ok, BUT the moment I try to import it:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-12786fe38199> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 from pyclustertend import hopkins

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/numba/__init__.py in _ensure_critical_deps()
    136         raise ImportError("Numba needs NumPy 1.17 or greater")
    137     elif numpy_version > (1, 20):
--> 138         raise ImportError("Numba needs NumPy 1.20 or less")
    139 
    140     try:

ImportError: Numba needs NumPy 1.20 or less

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Many thanks you all!

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use libraries that just can't be used together.  Perhaps there's a newer version of `numba` that you can upgrade to?

Comment: I guess I can try that directly in the code as a tried with !pip install pyclustertend (maybe?)